# Testing speed on Travis-CI vs. Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, testing, solr

On putting acts_as_solr_reload's test suite to run on Travis-CI the tests run on 3.84s, but on a dedicated server I ran it on 42s!

I'm looking to improve test speed on Ruby/Rails. In this case, an external server - Solr - is also involved in the tests.

Differences in hardware aren't probably the problem, cause the server has a Xeon X3430.

```
Loaded suite /home/braulio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
................................................................
Finished in 42.251154 seconds.

64 tests, 250 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

And on Travis-CI

```
Loaded suite /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
................................................................
Finished in 3.846992 seconds.

64 tests, 250 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

http://travis-ci.org/#!/coletivoEITA/acts_as_solr_reloaded/jobs/1376476/L172

How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the source code on a tmpfs did the trick!

Using only sqlite on the tmpfs reduced time from 42s to 35s.
Put solr and sqlite on the tmpfs reduced time to 2s.

/dev/shm can be used for a non-root tmpfs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Travis-CI and this is clearly a "fence" question but, are you sure the test environment has a solr server running and can you successfully use it?

Also, consider narrowing down which tests are running with which times. Running with a higher verbosity should give you a much better insight about time discrepancies.